# Washing husband's feet and drinking that water

Tags: marriage

The practice of washing the feet of one's husband and then drinking that water is prevalent across many Hindu communities.

A. Is this a compulsion for all married women?

B. Does it have scriptural sanction?

C. Which Devi has been mentioned to be the first one to observe this custom?

Answer (score 4):

> *B. Does it have scriptural sanction?*

Yes, this is what Śiva Purāṇa [says](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226118.html):

> #### Chapter 54 - Description of the duties of the chaste wife
>
> 24. Without the permission of her husband she shall not go even on pilgrimage. She shall eschew the desire to attend social festivities.
> 25. **If a women wants holy water she shall drink the same with which her husband’s feet have been washed. All holy rivers are present in that water.**
> 26. She shall partake of the leavings of her husband's food or whatever is given by him saying "This is thy great grace."

Comment: FYI : the same rule applies to husbands drinking washing their parent's/guru's feet and partaking that water. Everyone has to show humility/devotion towards someone. If someone asks why not have wife partake her parent's/guru's feet's water and husband partake wife's feet's water, they can also ask why not parents wash and partake their children's feet's water.

Comment: The relation between a parent and his/her offspring is not the same as that shared between a husband and wife